# Lag Issues With Moving A Circle

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, keylistener

So I was making a game for my Computer Science class, pretty much making a modified version of the game Frogger, and I first started off by just moving a circle across the JPanel to mimic the frogs movement and I realized a very annoying lag between the interactions with the buttons. Does anyone know how to completely get rid of the lag or perhaps reduce it? Any tips or help would be much appreciated! Here is the code so far for just the circle movement and if you see any improvements that could be done, please feel free to leave your comments.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class second extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener 
{
Timer t = new Timer (5, this);
double x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

public second()
{
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 10, 10));
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
    repaint();
    x += velx;
    y += vely;
}

public void up()
{
    vely = -5;
    velx = 0;
}

public void down()
{
    vely = 5;
    velx = 0;
}

public void left()
{
    velx = -5;
    vely = 0;
}

public void right()
{
    velx = 5;
    vely = 0;
}

public void upEnd()
{
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}

public void downEnd()
{
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}

public void leftEnd()
{
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}

public void rightEnd()
{
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}

public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
{
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        up();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        down();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        right();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        left();
    }
}

public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) 
{
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        upEnd();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        downEnd();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        rightEnd();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        leftEnd();
    }
}
}
```

And here is the Main file:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Macheads
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    second s = new second();
    f.add(s);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(800,600);
}
}
```

Comment: What kind of lag are you talking about? Could it be because when you release one button, you set both the x and y velocities to zero? What if I'm holding up and right and then let go of right but keep holding in up?

Comment: When I press an arrow key, it moves it 5 to the direction of the key and then a pause of around 2 seconds, then it continues on moving and this happens every time another key is pressed.

Comment: And this code causes that to happen? I really wouldn't expect that. Are you sure you aren't doing the incrementing from your KeyListener?

Comment: Yea like it's very strange. It won't be lagging at some moments and others it will always happen when you change directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using Key Bindings.

The keyboard has a delay for repeating events. Use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation instead of relying on key events to be generated. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only the keyListener without the timer and actionlistener.

```
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
{
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        up();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        down();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        right();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        left();
    }
     x += velx;
     y += vely;
    repaint(); //added and will repaint everytime key is pressed
}

//no need to place arguments in keyTyped and keyReleased because JPanel is repainted on keypressed...
```